# How to open YouTube or Netflix Android app via DIAL?

Tags: android, youtube

My client on Android:YouTube or Netflix native app.

My server on Android:
Reference to [DIAL server sample](https://github.com/Netflix/dial-reference),
I can open Youtube by chrome use

```
am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d "https://www.youtube.com/tv?pairingCode=eac4ae42-8b54-4441-9be3-d8a9abb5c481&v=cKG5HDyTW8o&t=0&additionalDataUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A56789%2Fapps%2FYouTube%2Fdial_data%3F"
```

While how can I open YouTube or Netflix native app like that?